# Linux, PHP: не изменяется значение «sendmail_path»

Tags: php, linux

1. Беру `php.ini`:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
   ```
2. Изменяю `;sendmail =` на `sendmail = <my/path>`.
3. Сохраняю изменения.
4. Перегружаю сервер:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
5. Перехожу на мой `phpinfo()`:

   ```
   http://test/php/info.php
   ```
6. Значение `sendmail_path` не изменилось:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/sendmail
   ```

---

**В чём может быть причина?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Причина в том, что вы изменяете конфигурацию для PHP-клиента, а не модуля Apache. Вам нужно изменить соответствующее значение в следующем файле:

```
sudo vim /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```